# Concave Utility Function Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

For the last few days, I have been trying to replicate the following figure with TikZ (I am open to use pgfplots, but I have not been able to achieve much with pgfplots so far; therefore I am using TikZ).

[image: Plot to Replicate]

The picture below shows the closest I have been able to get using TikZ. The code below the picture is a WME of the code I use to get the plot.

[image: My Plot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0.01:6.5]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$\cdot$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6.5) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$};
\draw[densely dotted, domain=0.2:3.3] plot (\x, 2.5+\x);
\draw[thick, smooth, samples=100, yshift=4.6cm, domain=0.01:6.5] plot ({ \x, ln(\x)});
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (0,2.7) -- (0.15,2.7) node[left] {$u(x)$};
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (0,5.8) -- (3.3,5.8) node[left] {$u(y)$};
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (0,4.25) -- (1.75,4.25);
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (0.15,0) -- (0.15,2.75);
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (1.75,0) -- (1.75,5.15);
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (3.25,0) -- (3.25,5.75);
\draw[-, thin, densely dotted] (0,5.15) -- (1.75,5.15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If possible, I would like some help in making my plot look like the one in the first picture. Though solutions with TikZ are preferred, I am open to do it with pgfplots from scratch. Can Anyone help me in achieving my goal? Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do all the calculations within Ti*k*Z, the same syntax `\coordinate (a) at (0.5,{ln(0.5)})` works to set a coordinate in some specific point of the plot, in this case, it's `u(0.5)`.

There's only one tricky part which is the `c(F,u)`, there it's possible to use the `intersections` library to brutally determine that coordinate, or do it with math. But to use math one must know that once Ti*k*Z computes a dimension it internally converts it into `pt` and since the plot is being handled in `cm` a unit conversion must be done: `1cm=28.4576pt` and `1pt=0.03514cm`. Now, knowing the an `y` (`u(x)`) value we can determine ist corresponding `x` by doing `x=pow(e,y)` where `y` must be given in `cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={
                        thick,
                        smooth,
                        samples=100,
                        domain=0.1:5},
                    my grid/.style={dashed,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}},
                    my axis/.style={latex-latex}]
\draw[my plot] (0,0) plot (\x,{ln(\x)});
\coordinate (start plot) at (0.1,{ln(0.1)}); % domain start
\coordinate (end plot) at (5,{ln(5)}); % domain end
\draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[left] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[below] {$\cdot$}; %creates the axis a little bigger than the plot and also sepatared
\def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55} % define the x, y and p values
\coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{ln(\x)}); % set the u(x) coordinate
\coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{ln(\y)}); % set the u(y) coordinate
\coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{ln(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)}); % set the u(p*x+(1-p)*y) coordinate
\draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy); % set the coordinate on the linear curve
\path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2); %this is the most tricky part explained in the answer
% with everything set, just draw the lines:
\draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(x)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below right,font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[left]{$u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up-mid2) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$c(F,u)$} (origin) |- node[left]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)$} cycle;
\draw[my grid] (Up-mid) -- (Up-mid2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```